# How to update a table with updated data from same table

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL 15, I'm trying to update a table while reading from that same table (for each row). Simplified example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE a ( id bigint );
INSERT INTO a ( id ) VALUES ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 );
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE b ( id bigserial, a bigint );
INSERT INTO b ( a ) VALUES ( 0 ), ( 0 ), ( 0 );
```

Table a contents:

```
 id 
----
  1
  2
  3
```

Table b contents:

```
 id | a 
----+---
  1 | 0
  2 | 0
  3 | 0
```

Now I would like to update each row of table `b`, and set `a` to a value that does not exist in table `b`.

I have tried:

```
UPDATE b SET a = (
  SELECT MIN(a.id)
  FROM a
  WHERE a.id NOT IN ( SELECT a FROM b )
);
SELECT * FROM b;
```

But the output is always all 1 or all 2 after each update. I need `SELECT a FROM b` to be executed for each row.

Other things I've tried are [recursive CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30274141/update-a-table-recursively-in-postgres), and WHERE NOT EXISTS, different TABLE LOCK modes (within a transaction).

There seems to be some zip-like function for arrays, using `unnest`, but that is not for entire tables.

How can I update table `b` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, a window function `row_number()` is the safest and clearest way to achieve what I think you want.  For instance, you can change the `existing` cte in case you want to update only the rows where `a = 0`:

```
with available as (
  select id, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
    from a 
   where not exists (select 1 from b where a = a.id)
), existing as (
  select *, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
    from b
), changes as (
  select e.id as b_id, a.id as new_a
    from existing e
         join available a on a.rn = e.rn
)
update b
   set a = new_a
  from changes
 where changes.b_id = b.id;
```

[Working fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qTWufB1M)

Comment: Thanks for the approach! This will definitely solve my problem of populating a database with (more or less) random data for demo / testing purposes.